# Adding Sequence Number (Header) to Packets - VoIP - Java

Tags: java, numbers, sequence, voip, packet

Im working on developing a basic voice over IP system in java. Where audio can be sent back n forth with a sender and receiver using threads. However, their is some packet loss when using different datagram packets. Therefore i am trying add a header for each packet that is sent so that is easier to identify which exact packet is lost when receiving, so we can develop some compensation methods.

I've started something but I'm not sure if its the rich idea, the general idea was to add 2 bytes to the array, and allocated those 2 extra bytes to the header information, that being a sequential number for each packet...

```
 Vector<byte[]> voiceVector = new Vector<byte[]>();

 int recordTime = 30;

 System.out.println("Recording Audio...");

 for (int i = 0; i < Math.ceil(recordTime / 0.032); i++)

 byte[] block = recorder.getBlock();

 DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(fPacket, fPacket.length, clientIP, PORT);

 //Send it
 sending_socket.send(packet);
 voiceVector.add(block);
```

Anyone got any ideas? I know ill beed to create a new array that contains the voice vector and the 2 extra bytes but am unsure how to do this as I havnt used java in some time...

Cheers

Comment: sequencing and loss are covered by the higher level TCP protocol.  Also, I think there was work on an intermediary (between TCP and UDP) protocol for VOIP use, but I cant recall the name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you implement this using TCP first and only when this is working attempt it using UDP.  Reliable UDP is a complex subject and detecting dropped packets is just the start.

Even if you have to send the same audio to many receivers, it can still be simpler to use TCP. (And perhaps a faster network card if you have to)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use TCP - it will add overheads on latency due to its acknowledgments.
What you should probably do is use an implementation of RTP as your transport of packets. It runs over UDP and adds timestamps and other things you will find useful and needed.

Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol

Don't implement it on your own - find a ready-made library that is already doing that.